# Docker build Nestjs and React build folder disappears

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to build Nestjs and ReactJS in Docker with Dockerfile + Docker-Compose.

I can see NestJS builds fine and runs as it should. However, ReactJS build directory is completely missing and I do see the logs of React scripts build doing its thing when I run Docker build. I can't figure out why it's missing. Here's my Dockerfile

```
RUN mkdir -p /home/node/app
WORKDIR /home/node/app
COPY .npmrc ./
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install --production=false
COPY . .

// NOTE this build command runs 2 commands
// npm run build-server && npm run build-client
// both point to different directories
RUN npm run build 


FROM testDev as prod
ENV PORT 3000
EXPORT 3000

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

Expecting it to build and not disappear/delete the Build folder.